# Letting indoor cats out for the first time

Tags: cats

I used to live in an apartment with two cats, they’ve never been outdoors, do you think is wise to let them out now that I live in a standalone house with a garden ?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please have a look at the [tour] and [help], especially the topic [Dont ask](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). It states *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site ..."*. You'll get 5 different answers from 3 users to your question as it is now. Can you concentrate on one specific problem or risk, maybe add more information (like where you live) and [edit] your question to keep it [on-topic](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I think this question needs more information to be answerable - in particular, how old are the cats (younger cats will be more adaptable to change than older ones), and where do you live (urban/suburban, near a main road or in country, as much relevant information as possible) - some environments will be safer for a "non-streetwise" cat than others.

Comment: I'm curious why you feel this is necessary. Cats can not only live long, full, happy lives as indoor-only cats, but will generally live longer and be healthier. Especially if these have been indoor-only cats their whole lives, it's very unlikely to be a good or safe idea to let them out.

Answer (score 3):

It should be fine. With my cats, we kept them in the new home for a few weeks so they could get used to the new surroundings and watch through the windows, and let them out a little later. All went fine!

However, some cats might not want to go out after being inside for their whole lives, and they should obviously not be forced out.

You could start by going outside with them together

Comment: It might be important to make sure they are neutered too!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to let your cats outdoors. Cats face a multitude of threats outdoors: FelV, FIV, other species, worms, ticks, fleas.

Our shelter does not adopt out to people who say they are going to let the cat outdoors unless the cat is a "barn buddy."

https://pets.thenest.com/whats-normal-indoor-cat-lifespan-10139.html

Comment: You might want to include this pets.se answer as a reference in your answer https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/5548/13